# SS34 in-line Schottky alternative

Tags: diodes, bridge-rectifier, schottky, barrier

Is there an inline alternative to this part I can replace it with?

With my limited electronics knowledge and the ability to google I know this is a surface mount diode rectifier but that’s about as much as I understand.

For some reason the manufacturer of this wiring loom used a surface mount component on an inline wire and it’s broken off.

It would seem to me it would be more resilient to movement with an inline version but I don’t know how to find a 100% compatible version of such a thing.

Can anyone tell me what I could use instead? From what I can tell the banded end is the cathode.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the [SB340](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88719/sb320.pdf).  It's pretty much a through-hole equivalent of your surface mount part.